# ERROR 1030 (HY000): Got error -1 from storage engine

Tags: php, mysql

When I try to insert data into MySQL database I got this error:

Error Msg

```
#1030 - Got error -1 from storage engine
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you searched for this error? What platform are you on (Win/Linux/OSX)? What have you found in researching this issue? What query are you using that triggers this? Do all queries result in this error?

Comment: Which version of MySQL are You using?

Comment: Yikes, an upvote! @Ruban, please consider taking the feedback above on board with your questions generally. You'll find this site operates quite differently to many others; evidence of prior attempt and/or research is fairly mandatory here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you do is check whether you are out of disk space.This error probably means you don't have enough memory for allocating to your table or database, or the specified memory settings for MySQL are too high for the configuration of your machine.

the following link may be useful to you http://wiki.jumpbox.com/doc/runtime/faq/mysql_maintenance

Comment: I hope you could have just posted the answer here. The link's broken.